# ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

This code gave me an **ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"**

```
SELECT name_one, name_two, jaro(
   select name from clients limit 50 as name_one, 
   select name from clients limit 50 as name_two
);
```

This works fine:

```
select jaro('aaa','aaa');
```

But now i need to get data from tables

Comment: What are you trying to select?

Comment: The problem is that `jaro()` wants a value for each parameter, but you're supplying a table of 50 names.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  name_1 | name_2 | jaro value

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name POSTGRES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can select `jaro(name1, name2)` for all pairs of names:

```
SELECT
    t1.name as name1
,   t2.name as name2
,   jaro(t1.name, t2.name) as jaro
FROM
   (select name from clients limit 50) t1
CROSS JOIN
    (select name from clients limit 50) t2
```

This query uses a so-called self [*cross join*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) - it produces all pairs of names from your `clients` table.

Comment: @user2983258 Apart from the call of your `jaro` function which you said works fine for you, the query should be fine ([see its shortened version on sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/da6f0/2)).

Comment: @user2983258 You are right, I was missing a `FROM` in the post (the demo included it, though).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
SELECT name, jaro(name, name)
FROM clients limit 50
```

Right? Or which are the columns you want to pass to `jaro()`?